# Can't set a signed SSL certificate on NodeJS/expressJS

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, express

I'm trying to set a signed certificate to set an HTTPS sever on nodejs.
But I keep getting the following error in chrome (and similar on other browsers).

```
"Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error."
```

When I ran the same code with self signed certificate and it worked OK.

Then I ran openssl verify and seems like the certificate is OK.

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile ./ca.crt server.crt
server.crt: OK
```

This is how I run it with the signed certificate:

```
    var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.key').toString();
    var certificate = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.crt').toString();
    var ca = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/ca.crt').toString();
    var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate, ca: ca};

    //Start Server
    https.createServer(credentials, app).listen(httpsPort, function () {
        console.log("Listening on port " + httpsPort + ' (https)');
    });
```

Comment: Is your Skype running and not unbound from 443 port? Are some ESET protection software set? Are you using SSL 2.0 and Chrome is on the latest version? Is your browser's cache cleared?

Comment: As I said it all works when I'm using self signed certificate so I guess all the issues with the SSL version/skype are not relevant

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, it was my mistake the server.key didn't match the server.crt.
A simple test found it.

See: http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#cert-test

```
openssl s_server -cert mycert.pem -www
```